# Highlight cell if it falls in a list of dates

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a weekly sales summary where I would like to highlight if the weekending date falls in a week with a public holiday in it.

I can use conditional formatting for a date range or single date but can't find a method of comparing the weekending date with a list of dates to show if a public holiday falls in that week.

The weekending date is always a Sunday but the public holiday dates could be any week day, so a range of Monday-Friday will be necessary i.e. weekend 13/12/2015 would need to look at 07/12/15-11/12/15.

I suspect conditional formatting cannot cope with this and a formula in an adjacent column will be fine.  VBA is also fine.

Comment: Excel has `WEEKNUM()`, which you could use on your holiday dates and your cells to be highlighted.  A formula-based CF rule should work using that.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Tim Williams, and assuming you have a list of holiday dates, say in ColumnH starting in H1, you might enter in I1 and copy down to suit:

```
=WEEKNUM(H1)
```

then select your other column of dates (assumed to be ColumnA) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=WEEKNUM(A1)=VLOOKUP(WEEKNUM(A1),I:I,1,0)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of formatting, OK, OK.

Note this only works for one year at a time.

Comment: this worked nicely, thank you. The complication is the final week of the year, though, where Weeknum 53 would usually be included in week 1 of the following year.  This doesn't appear as a relevant date within the analysis being carried out but I'll see if extending the formula to include INDEX and MATCH will take this into account.  Does conditional formatting accept array formulas?